# How to remove labels in ant-design donut chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, components, antd, donut-chart

I am trying to remove all the labels from the donut chart in @ant-design/plots.

How to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve this in 2 ways**

1. Setting content property of label object to an empty string.

> `content:""`

```
 label: {
       type: "inner",
       offset: "-50%",
       content: "",
       style: {
         textAlign: "center",
         fontSize: 14,
       },
     },
```

2. Setting fontSize to 0 in the style object.

> `fontSize:0`

```
label: {
  type: "inner",
  offset: "-50%",
  content: "{value}",
  style: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 0,
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just set label to false

label: false,

Comment: Please read [answer] and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and take the [tour] and try to improve your post by [edit]ing it.